# With Apache, is it possible to generate a directory listing for a non-folder URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, directoryindex

Apache allows you to create a directory list (when configured) if you visit a folder with no index.html.

What I want to know is, is it possible to get that same list but at a different URL? I'm already using index.html and *want to keep it that way*.

i.e., this is what I'm looking for:

`http://example.com/blar/` -> loads my index.html page (don't want this to change)
`http://example.com/blar/directory_list` (I want this url to render the apache directory list instead)

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, and you want /blar/directory_list to return with the directory listing of /blar ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I have solved my particular problem with a PHP script to generate my own listing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would solve that using a [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) override on the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
...
Alias /bar /var/www/foo
<Location /bar>
    DirectoryIndex disabled
</Location>
```

Now http://domain.tld/foo/ will present your index.html while http://domain.tld/bar/ will give you a directory index. Assuming your other configuration is in order that is.

Comment: Thanks for the clever hack! I was hoping for a solution that could be applied to the folder and all subfolders, ideally with a .htaccess setting. I'll accept this answer since I don't think what I wanted is possible.